# How to join 3 relation table using typeorm nestjs

Tags: mysql, express, nestjs, typeorm

I am using typeorm with NestJs, I try to join 3 relations but got an error   `path comment.user in entity was not found`

Here is my table User

| Id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |

```
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  username: string;
  @OneToMany(() => PostEntity, (post) => post.user, { eager: true })
  posts: PostEntity[];
```

Here is my table  Posts

| Id | desc | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | 1 |

```
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  desc: string;
  @Column()
  userId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts, {
    eager: false,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  user: User[];
  @OneToMany(() => CommentEntity, (comment: CommentEntity) => comment.post, {
    eager: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  comment: CommentEntity[];
```

Here is my table  comment

| Id | comment | user_id | postId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | comment post 1 | 1 | 1 |

```
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  comment: string;
  @Column()
  userId: number;
  @Column()
  postId: number;
  @ManyToOne(() => PostEntity, () => (post: PostEntity) => post.comment, {
    eager: false,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })

  post: PostEntity[];
  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
```

In here I use OneToOne because 1 comment can comment by only 1 user

this is what my data look like

````
```
this.createQueryBuilder('post')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.comment', 'comment')
      .select(['post', 'user.id', 'user.username', 'comment'])
      .getMany();
```
````

this is what I get

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'comment post 1',
    userId: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'row',
    },
    comment: [
      {
        id: 1,
        description: 'comment',
        userId: 1,
        postId: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

In comment I want to join userId for user that comment . I want data look like this

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'comment post 1',
    userId: 1,
    user: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'row',
    },
    comment: [
      {
        id: 1,
        description: 'comment',
        userId: 1,
        postId: 1,
        user: {
          // if different user comment will show different username
          id: 1, 
          username: 'row',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is what I try to do

```
this.createQueryBuilder('post')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.comment', 'comment')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.comment.user', 'user') 
      .select(['post', 'user.id', 'user.username', 'comment'])
      .orderBy('post.updated_at', 'DESC')
      .getMany();


 .leftJoinAndSelect('post.comment.user', 'user') // In this line I want to join userId but Its show an error  path comment.user in entity was not found
```

**UPDATE**

I try to use this ( this mean PostEntity)

```
this.find({ relations: ['user', 'comment', 'comment.user']
```

but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your `Comment` entity's user relationship like this:

```js
@OneToOne(() => User)
@JoinColumn({name: 'userId'})
user: User;
```

Then try:

```js
this.createQueryBuilder('post')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('post.comment', 'comment')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('comment.user', 'commentedUser') 
      .select(['post', 'user.id', 'user.username', 'comment', 'commentedUser'])
      .orderBy('post.updated_at', 'DESC')
      .getMany();
```

Comment: didn't work I got same result. Do I have to change or add any entity about commentedUser ?

Comment: comment is return in an array so am not sure how to work with that

Comment: I updated my answer, could you check now. (You don't need to do anything about `commentedUser` it is just an alias)

Comment: I try the still not return userDaata in post.comment[]

Comment: no error  but the user still didnt join I already add   @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })

Comment: Then try changing this `.select(['post', 'user.id', 'user.username', 'comment', 'commentedUser'])`

Comment: Glad to be of help. Good luck! 